# Unable to extend partitions using GParted

Tags: partitioning, 15.10, gparted

I'm on Ubuntu 15.10. My current partition state is as shown in the image.

[image]

I had Ubuntu 12.04 installed on a 19.22 GB partition, and I removed it and deleted the partition. Now I want to extend /dev/sda2 to include the 19.22 GB unallocated space that's right after it. However, GParted won't let me do that.

I think it has something to do with the hierarchical way the partitions are presented (the unallocated space seems to be a part of /dev/sda4 somehow), but I have no idea how to solve this.

Comment: You cannot do that from within your installed Ubuntu system, because it require modifying the partition on which it is installed. Try from a Live CD.

Comment: @fkraiem but ubuntu is installed on sda5. I want to extend sda2.

Comment: /dev/sda5 is located inside the extended partition /dev/sda4, and you need to shrink /dev/sda4.

Comment: There's no easy way to do this. The unallocated space is indeed within the extended partition. You would need to backup ext4 to external media, boot a live medium, swap off sda6, delete sda6 and sda4, extend sda2, then remake your extended partition and reinstall ubuntu to it.

Comment: This is a bad idea. The unallocated space is inside an extended partition, and can not be easily merged to sda2.

Comment: You can move unallocated at front(or end, but not middle) of extended partition to unallocated outside the extended partition. But little key symbols show mounted partition(s), so must use live installer's copy of gparted or gparted ISO and may have to swapoff to unmount swap as live installer likes to use it. Just shrink beginning of extended. But use Windows to expand NTFS partition.

Comment: @chaskes, you are wrong: there's no need to delete sda6 and sda4.

Comment: @user300458 I think it's a bad idea to more the start of partitions, so that assumption is build into my comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to grow primary partition sda2, the unallocated space must be immediately adjacent.  Currently it is within extended partition sda4.

The steps are:

1. Boot from live media containing GParted, e.g. [GParted Live](http://gparted.org/livecd.php).
2. Shrink extended partition sda4 to butt up against sda5.
3. Grow primary partition sda2 into the adjacent unallocated space.

See also [Moving Space Between Partitions](http://gparted.org/display-doc.php?name=moving-space-between-partitions)

Answer (score 1):

/dev/sda4 is an extended partition where your free space is and what has been a logical partition.
/dev/sda2 is a primary partion. You could merge the space with /dev/sda5 (and /dev/sda6) if you boot from a Live-CD/DVD/USB as fkraiem has already told.

You cannot "move" the space from an extended partion to a primary one. Have a closer look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_partitioning.