# Unable to extend partition to adjacent unallocated space

Tags: partitioning, gparted

Looking at this related question: [Unable to extend partitions using GParted](https://askubuntu.com/questions/771409/unable-to-extend-partitions-using-gparted), I followed the link to [Moving Space Between Partitions](https://gparted.org/display-doc.php?name=moving-space-between-partitions).

Following the cookbook in the latter, I have an unallocated 14 Gb adjacent to the partition I'd like to extend. This is what the partitions look like before:

[image: GParted picture]

But when I select the /dev/sdb1 partition and try to resize/move it in GParted, I can't extend:
[image: cannot extend]

(Note that the up-arrow for increasing the size is grayed out.)

How can I extend /dev/sdb1 over the adjacent unallocated space?

Comment: Delete the extended partition `sdb2` first.

Comment: thanks, @mook765, deleting the extended partition was key. GParted is now able to resize /dev/sdb1. If you make your comment into an answer, I will be glad to accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Partitions cannot overlap and next to the partition you want to grow (`sdb1`) is the extended partition `sdb2`.

The purpose of the extended partition is to hold logical partitions, but in your case, a logical partition does not exist, so the extended partition is not needed and can simply be deleted.

After deletion of `sdb2` you will be able to increase the size of `sdb1`.